# Accessing a hidden form using MechanicalSoup will result in "Value Error: No closing quotation"

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, mechanicalsoup

First of all my english is not my native language.

## Problem

I try to access and manipulate a form using MechanicalSoup as described in the [docs](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#first-contact-step-by-step). I did successfull login to the page using the given login form which I found using the "debug mode"(F12) built into chrome.

```
form action="https://www.thegoodwillout.de/customer/account/loginPost/"
```

The Form can be found *[here](https://www.thegoodwillout.de/customer/account/login/)* using the chrome "debugger"

this is working fine and will not produce any error. I tried to up my game and move to a more complicated form which is given on *[this](https://www.thegoodwillout.de/nike-air-vortex-schwarz-weiss-anthrazit-903896-010)* site. I managed to track down the form to this snippet

```
form action="https://www.thegoodwillout.de/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuZGUvbmlrZS1haXItdm9ydGV4LXNjaHdhcnotd2Vpc3MtYW50aHJheml0LTkwMzg5Ni0wMTA_X19fU0lEPVU,/product/115178/form_key/r19gQi8K03l21bYk/"
```

This will result in a

```
ValueError: No Closing quotation
```

which is weird since it does not use any special characters and I double checked so that every quotation is closing correctly

## What have I tried

I tried tracking down a more specific form which will apply for the given shoe size but this form seems to manage all the content on the Website. I searched the web and found several articles pointing to a *[bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1273589)* inside python which I cannot believe will be true!

## Source Code with attached error log

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("https://www.thegoodwillout.de/nike-air-vortex-schwarz-weiss-anthrazit-903896-010")
browser.select_form('form[action="https://www.thegoodwillout.de/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuZGUvbmlrZS1haXItdm9ydGV4LXNjaHdhcnotd2Vpc3MtYW50aHJheml0LTkwMzg5Ni0wMTA_X19fU0lEPVU,/product/115178/form_key/r19gQi8K03l21bYk/"]')
```

> NOTE: it all seems to track down to a module called shlex which is causing the error

Finally the *[error log](https://pastebin.com/X1ML8k0L)*

It would be really helpful if you could point me into the right directions and link some Websites I may not have fully investigated yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually an issue with BeautifulSoup4, the library used by MechanicalSoup to navigate within HTML documents, related to the fact that you use a comma (`,`) in the CSS selector.

BeautifulSoup splits CSS selectors on commas, and therefore considers your query as: `browser.select_form('form[action="https://www.thegoodwillout.de/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuZGUvbmlrZS1haXItdm9ydGV4LXNjaHdhcnotd2Vpc3MtYW50aHJheml0LTkwMzg5Ni0wMTA_X19fU0lEPVU` and `/product/115178/form_key/r19gQi8K03l21bYk/"]`, parsed separately. When parsing the first, it finds an opening `"` but no closing `"`, and errors out.

It's somewhat a feature (you can specify multiple CSS selectors as argument to `select`), but it's useless here as a feature (there's no point providing several selectors when you expect a single object).

Solution: don't use commas in CSS selectors. You probably have other criteria to match your form.

You may try using `%2C` instead of the comma (untested).